# Difference between nominal operating point and optimal operating point of induction machine

Tags: induction-motor

I am trying to draw Heyland drawing for an induction machine where it is said that the nominal operating point is equal to the optimal operating point. I am confused about the difference between the two operating points. Further, how could this information be translated to the Heyland diagram?

Comment: If it is said that they are the same, then that means that there is no difference. They are the same. "Optimal" means something is optimized (possibly efficiency). "Nominal" means expected or rated (Nominal is typically what is listed on the name plate for the machine).

Answer (score 1):

For a general purpose motor, the nominal operating point is the speed and torque point at which the motor is producing the maximum torque at which it can operate continuously without overheating.

The optimum operating point would usually be the operating point at which the motor efficiency is maximum.

Ordinarily, the operating voltage and frequency would be assumed to be the nominal design voltage and frequency.

The circle diagram seems to be more about the limits of performance rather than continuous performance at a safe operating point. I don't know how it is useful in the context of rated operation.

The diagram below shows current, torque, efficiency and power-factor vs. speed for a typical polyphase induction motor. The full-load line defines nominal operation. At that point, the nominal speed is about 0.96 PU speed and peak efficiency occurs slightly about 0.97 PU speed, so the nominal and optimal operating points are quite close together. The torque curve should cross the full load line at 1.) PU torque but it doesn't.

[image]

Image from Alger, *The Nature of Polyphase Induction Machines*, 1951 General Electric Co.

**Efficiency**

To draw a circle diagram, you must have data from no-load, locked-rotor and DC resistance tests. From that, you can determine values for R1, R2, Rm,(X1+X2) and Xm. Then you can do the proper calculation for efficiency vs. slip for mechanical power developed in the rotor. I believe that you need to neglect mechanical losses. If you assume that the slip for maximum efficiency is also the slip for rated motor operation, you can determine the current and power factor for rated motor operation and show the rated operating point on the circle diagram.

Comment: Efficiency =1-s, so that means efficiency would be maximum for slip being zero which wouldn't be much intersting point for a motor to run.. Correct me if i am mistaken

Comment: At slip = zero, there is no output, but there are losses, so efficiency = zero.

Comment: thanks. Would it be possible to relate between efficiency and slip or sny other physical quantity e.g. voltage?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but I will add an image that might be of interest.